# SASS Replicating nested selector

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm using SASS for a project and so far I'm pretty satisfied with it.
However I have some code that should only be presented for IE 7 and below, using the class name `.ie-lt8` for that. But when i extend that selector in SASS, with a nested selector i create multiple selectors.

Example (extending a `display: inline-block` code for IE):

SASS

```css
/* My extension code */
.ie-lt8 %ie-inline-block {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

/* I want the li to be inline-block */
#my-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    @extend %ie-inline-block;
}
```

CSS produced

```css
/* My extension code */
.ie-lt8 #my-ul, #my-ul .ie-lt8 li {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

/* I want the li to be inline-block */
#my-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Generally this is just fine, but the `#my-ul .ie-lt8 li` worries me a little. In this example it's ok as the code works fine with both selector (the mentioned selector just doesn't exists). But what if i have another code where the selector DOES matter, then this would cause a problem.

A thought example:

SASS

```css
/* I want the div to get a red border, 
   but the div inside .container to have a green border */
#myid .container div { border: 5px dotted green; }
#myid div {
    @extend %red-border;
}

/* My extension code */
.container %red-border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

CSS it would produce

```css
/* I want the div to get a red border, 
   but the div inside .container to have a green border */
#myid .container div { border: 5px dotted green; }

/* My extension code */
.container #myid div, #myid .container div {
    border: 1px solid red; /* [OVERRIDE OF THE BORDER] */
}
```

My question is then; is there a way to make SASS only take the initial selector, without creating multiple selectors from a nested selector (a lot of selectors in one sentence)?

I tried gooling for this issue, but i find it hard to find any articles/blogs/etc. regarding this issue.

**UPDATE**

I'm aware of various workarounds, such as using @mixin's instead. I was just wondering whether there was something i missed regardig SASS, or if someone could tell me why this is? Cause it seems to me like it's kind of a bug.

Comment: why not extend the complete selector instead (i.e. `.ie-lt8 %ie-inline-block`)?

Comment: Well to make it easy. As I write my code more inline-block elements will appear and then i can just include the `@extend %ie-inline-block;` chunk to those declarations, instead of having to scroll to another place in my document each time. One of the reasons for using pre-compilers like SASS should be to make such trivial thing easier. right?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is in **SCSS** - not **SASS** so you'll have to convert...

For browser targeting like this, I would recommend using mixins, and furthermore - @content within a @mixin to achieve your desired results.  It also sets up a much more understandable set of rules with context.

For your specific example, it's as simple as moving your inline-block fix into a mixin instead of declaring only as a class.

```
@mixin ie7-inline-block {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
} 

#my-ul li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    .ie-lt8 & {
        @include ie7-inline-block;
    }
}
```

Even better than that though, by using @content, you can always ensure that your style is prefixed with .ie-lt8 by making a mixin like so:

```
@mixin ie7 {
    .ie-lt8 & {
        @content;
    }
}

#my-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    @include ie7 {
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
}
```

Which will output the same css, but allows your IE7-Specific styles to be wrapped each time in some context that makes sense to anyone who reads your code.

Comment: eeeehhh... I think you are confusing things here: SCSS IS SASS! .scss is just the extension SASS uses for the files, it has to compile. That said: yes you could be right, but I don't want to bloat the final .css result file too much with repetitive code.

Comment: @Tokimon .sass is not the same thing as .scss - they are two different syntaxes.  They both use the "Sass" compiler - but they are different language specs.  I was simply saying that my code example was written using the .scss syntax.

Comment: yeah ok in some way you're right. In sass-lang.com they refer to it as the shorthand method, so I would still say that it's the same, but different in its syntax because of the shortend syntax.